# Harmonic Series

Tags: java, php

I'm having an issue in getting a PHP script moved over to Java. I'm working with a harmonic series set. I have it working in PHP, but when I convert it to Java, it never ends (infinite loop). Any ideas? Or even a better way to get it done?

The PHP:

```
<?php

$current = 0;
$num = 2.5;

while($current < $num) {
    for($i = 1; $current < $num; $i++) {
        $current = $current + (1 / $i);
    }

    // this ($current) will return "2.5928571428571" (which it should)
    echo $current;
}

?>
```

The Java (the Java equivalent, but not finishing the loop):

```
double current = 0;
double num = 2.5;
int i = 0;

while(current < num) {
    for(i = 1; current < num; i++) {
        current = current + (1 / i);
    }

    System.out.println(current);
}
```

Or maybe I'm totally doing it wrong :o.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's that `while` loop for?

Comment: Java is strongly typed whereas php is not, and will do type conversion for you.  As mentioned, when you attempt to divide a number with an integer, java assumes you have an integer result, and throws away your floating point result, so you never actually add anything to current, and this results in your endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

current never goes beyond 1 since 1/n=0 where n > 1.

A couple points:

1. There should be no need to have the while loop or declare i outside the for loop
2. use a double type

Answer (score 1):

Use double numbers, not ints since int division will do funny things.

the fraction uses int literals, and int division *must* return an int, in your case it will often return 0 if i > 1

i.e.,

```
current = current + (1 / i); // will return current + 0 if i > 1
```

Better to make the numerator a double literal by changing 1 to 1.0:

```
current = current + (1.0 / i);
```

Now double division will do what you expect division should do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with type casting. PHP doesn't care about types in this case, so it works there.

In Java, on the other hand, you need to force the `double` type on your division for this to work.

```
double current = 0;
double num = 2.5;
int i = 0;

while(current < num) {
    for(i = 1; current < num; i++) {
        current += (1.0 / i); // Force the result to be a decimal with 1.0
    }
System.out.println(current);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just make `i` a `double` to start with.

```
...
for(double i = 1.0; current < num; i+=1.0)
  current += 1.0/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate variable just to see if the sum is the problem and being able to debug.

```js
double current = 0;
double num = 2.5;
double inc;

while(current < num) {
    for(int i = 1; current < num; i++) {
        inc = 1 / (double)i;
        current += inc;
    }
System.out.println(current);
}
```

If it solves your problem the the final code can be

```js
double current = 0;
double num = 2.5;

while(current < num) {
    for(int i = 1; current < num; i++) {
        current += (1 / (double)i);
    }
System.out.println(current);
}
```

Comment: Why cast in the middle of the calculation if you can just make `i` a `double` in the final code?

Comment: @Jon, True. Although there is no "cast in the middle", casting is done  at compilation time not runtime.

Comment: I meant your code is written with the cast in the middle of the calculation. IMO its cleaner to just make `i` a `double`. Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

int/int = int    (if result is suppose .07 int can't hold floating point number it will be 0) so

int/float = float (hope u got)